# Ventura not showing actual file name in search results

Tags: finder, search, ventura

When I search for AIF audio files in Finder, it shows me the file name "utf8". This is the media title, apparently. There does not appear to be a way for Finder to show me the file name.

Here is how Finder shows the files.
[image]

Here is what "Get Info" shows on the selected file from the above screenshot.
[image]

Terminal also shows the correct file name.
[image]

When I browser the folder using Finder WITHOUT SEARCHING then the file appears with the correct name.
[image]

Is this a BUG in Ventura search? I'd REALLY like it if Search could show me the actual filenames. How can this be resolved?

Comment: What do "Name & Extension" show in get info?

Comment: They show the same name that is in bold in the first line of the get info box.